# What is the use of Strictfp method in java?

Tags: java, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use “strictfp” keyword in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-to-use-strictfp-keyword-in-java)

What is the use of Strictfp method in java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strictfp` is a method or class modifier that forces the JVM to do floating point math a certain way that is guaranteed to be the same across different JVM implementations (stopping the JVM from cutting corners to improve performance and possibly lose some precision / accuracy).

More information can be found on the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp), but it's low on detail. Hardcore information (if you care) can be found in the [JVM spec](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201432943).

Answer (score 1):

`strictfp` makes sure that the floating-point operations in the marked code will act the same across all platforms.  It's something you might use in 2D/3D programming where you need to make certain you get exactly the same results regardless of what platform you run the program on.