# What is the use of strictfp modifier and synchronized keyword in main method of java

Tags: java, program-entry-point

```
public static synchronized strictfp void main(String... arg)
```

In the above statement, can someone please explain the purpose of `synchronized` and `strictfp` for `main` method.

Comment: main() method is supposed to be called by the JVM and should not be called by the programmer for internal use. Thus it should not be synchoronized

Comment: As for `strictfp` you may want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java). Sidenote: it is a keyword, not a modifier.

Comment: @Turing85 - It is a modifier, see [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3).

Comment: I don't think the `synchronized` modifier has a purpose, but it does have an effect - no thread will be able to synchronize on the class monitor for the life of the program (unless the main thread yields it by calling `wait()`).

Answer (score 0):

Few good explanation for java synchronized is given here - [what-does-synchronized-mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean) and [learning-java-use-of-synchronized-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196723/learning-java-use-of-synchronized-keyword)

Now, if main method is synchronized, only one thread can enter into this method, which is the java main thread (assuming that the class is executed as main class).

For executing this method, the main thread will acquire the class level lock (being a static method). So, if the class is having more static synchronized methods, those will be blocked forever for other thread, until main thread completes the execution or go into wait state.

strictfp is Java is explained [when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java) and [strictfp-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181256/strictfp-in-java)

It does not have any different behavior with `main()`.