# Different results for the floating point operations

Tags: java

I'm having a small issue, I have some code that calculates a mean value from a given set of data, I do this from several different computers (some with linux, some with windows, some 32bits and others 64bits), but when I watch the database results the some values that should be equal are slightly different.

This makes no difference for my program but I was wondering why it was this way, I was under the impression that floating point operations with the same word lenght should yield the same result (I was obviously wrong).

This is a small sample code that I wrote to check:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String... args){
        double counter = 0, value = 1./10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
            counter += value;
        }

        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

It basically calculates 1000000 / 10, I know that the result won't be exact but in some pcs it prints a number that is slightly less than 100000 and in other cases it prints a number slightly greater.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you **really** need the same error on all the platforms you should use the `strictfp` keyword in your method declaration, check out the selected answer on this post: [When should I use the "strictfp" keyword in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java)

Let it be noted that `strictfp` only works on your current block, and does not propagates though the code, so if you are calling some methods in the middle they should have `strictfp` too (also you should use `StrictMath` instead of `Math`).

At any rate if this is not affecting your code, just let it be... strict floating point operations have a higher computational cost that regular floating point operations.

Comment: Wow, I am doing Java for such a long time and I have read a lot about Java, but I have never heard of this keyword. Thanks for enlightening me. ^^

Comment: @user1335148 Yes, strictfp is a Java keyword!

Comment: @Fido Thanks for the tip, I've used java for a while now, and as MichaelSchmeißer have never heard of the strictfp keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I would think it depends on compiler optimization techniques used.  E.g. with no optimizations, you get a lot of addition, resulting in probably loss of precision, with a compiler that can understand the operations involved, the whole loop might be replaced with `counter = value*1000000`

The precision of `double` and its operations are set precisely in the language

Comment: Is it possible to manually set compiler optimizations on Java? or is it just a decision of the JVM? in which case nothing could be done...

Comment: Yes, you [can set](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/options.html) optimization options

Answer (score 1):

Different plate forms have different ways to represent floating point.

To get same results you should limit the precision to a specific number of decimal places.