# Math.pow yields different results upon repeated calls

Tags: java, math, jvm-hotspot, pow

After upgrading to Java 1.8.0_20 our test system reported errors, but the code was not changed. I found out, that `Math.pow()` called with exactly the same input parameters yields different results upon repreated calls. In Java 1.8.0_11 it behaves as expected and returns always the same value, but with Java 1.8.0_20 and above it sometimes returns slightly different values.

This is similar to the question [Math.pow yields different result depending on java version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404088/math-pow-yields-different-result-depending-on-java-version), but different because the results of pow() differ within one VM.

The following JUint test fails when run under Java 1.8.0_20 and higher

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.function.BiFunction;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PowerTest {

    private static final int N = 1000000;
    private static final double base = 5350.456329377186;
    private static final double exp = 2.0;

    private static double eval(final BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> f) {
        return f.apply(base, exp);
    }

    private void loop(final BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> f) {
        final double x = eval(f);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            final double p = eval(f);
            assertEquals("i=" + i, x, p, 0);
        }
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void info() {
        System.out.println("Java " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
    }

    @Test
    public void mathPow() {
        loop(Math::pow);
    }

    @Test
    public void strictMathPow() {
        loop(StrictMath::pow);
    }
}
```

Test does not fail under Java 1.8.0_11 or if the hotspot is turned of with `-Xint`. The strict math version of pow() yields consistent results. I suspect the hotspot JIT to do some optimizations that switch to a different implementation of pow(), which yields different results for certain input values. A mathematical function should be deterministic and should yield consistent and reproducible results.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 8):

I have found the following bug report:

[JDK-7021568 : Double.parseDouble() returns architecture dependent results](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7021568)

It is very similar in that it reports a floating-point operation returning slightly different results in JITed code vs interpreted code.

The issue is marked as a bug and has been fixed. On this basis I would argue that what you're seeing is also a bug and should be reported to Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug. I reported it to ORACLE (http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8063086), it was accepted and is fixed in Java 9.