# Non-deterministic Math.pow(x, 2) [Scala]

Tags: java, scala, double, precision, non-deterministic

In my code I started noticing that the same initial conditions would output different results.

After hours of hunting, I found where the bug occurs.

I have a simple function, which takes a few parameters, one of which is `v`. `v` is a double.
One of the calculations inside that function is `Math.pow(v, 2)`.

After writing some code that recorded all the inputs of that function and all the intermediate calculations inside that function, I've discovered that `v` is always equal `-54.35178459279`, but sometimes

```
Math.pow(-54.35178459279, 2) = 2954.116488421044
```

and sometimes (look at the ending 3)

```
Math.pow(-54.35178459279, 2) = 2954.1164884210443
```

What? What's going on?

---

I've tried running `Math.pow(-54.35178459279, 2)` in an infinite loop to see if it sometimes gives a different output. Well, it doesn't.

My only guesses so far is that either:

a. My debugger does not show all the digits in a number

b. That even though the debugger shows the same representation for `v`s, the underlying scala double is slightly different.

---

For those who really want an example, this is really the best I can do:

```
val precision = 1000000000000.0
def step(v: Double) = {
  val newV = Math.round(calcV(v)*precision) / precision
  step(newV)
}

def calcV(v: Double) = Math.pow(v, 2)
```

---

Just got a clue:

```
scala> -54.35178459279 * -54.35178459279
res0: Double = 2954.1164884210443
scala> Math.pow(-54.35178459279, 2)
res0: Double = 2954.116488421044
```

Comment: You may need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for this.

Comment: How did you calculate or assign the values of `v` that led to different square values?

Comment: Naive debugging guesses: try printing `v` with high precision, or try creating a `Set` of all the different `v` and see how big it is. Or cache the last value of `v` and see if it changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746623/math-pow-yields-different-results-upon-repeated-calls?

Comment: @djechlin Actually, I do cache the numbers. The two `v`s are identical in the cache (`cache(0) == cache(1) = true`)

Comment: @johny looks right. Closing as dupe, reopen if you find evidence o/w.

Comment: No, it's not. I downloaded java 8u66, and I still get the same error. It's the version on this page http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8063086.