# What does Strictfp means in java?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

If anyone can explain me what is strictfp in java with an example and a good explanation then that will be great. 
I have already search the internet but still I am unable to get the clear solution for the same
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use the "strictfp" keyword in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [explanation given by the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4) seems pretty clear:

> Within an FP-strict expression, all intermediate values must be elements of the float value set or the double value set, implying that the results of all FP-strict expressions must be those predicted by IEEE 754 arithmetic on operands represented using single and double formats.
>
> Within an expression that is not FP-strict, some leeway is granted for an implementation to use an extended exponent range to represent intermediate results; the net effect, roughly speaking, is that a calculation might produce "the correct answer" in situations where exclusive use of the float value set or double value set might result in overflow or underflow.

For a discussion of when one might use `strictfp`, see [When should I use the "strictfp" keyword in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java)

Comment: I read this but wanted some practical implemented answer such that I can have a clear idea about the same