# Why is Eclipse asking to declare strictfp inside enum

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, strictfp

I was trying out enum type in Java. When I write the below class,

```
public class EnumExample {
  public enum Day {
    private String mood;
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY;
    Day(String mood) {

    }
    Day() {

    }
  }
 }
```

Compiler says: `Syntax error on token String, strictfp expected.`
I do know what's `strictfp` but would it come here?

Comment: That's eclipse at its finest :D `strictfp` has nothing to do with strings, but with floating point arithmetic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java .

Comment: Eclipse will also give the same error, if you accidentally put a whitespace instead of an underscore in your constant declaration name. Like 'MONDAY_INT VALUE'

Answer (score 39):

You have maybe forgotten to add semicolon after last enum constant.

```
public enum Element {
    FIRE,
    WATER,
    AIR,
    EARTH,  // <-- here is the problem

    private String message = "Wake up, Neo";
}
```

Comment: That's correct. And this bites you when mocking enums where you don't even have enum values. The solution then is to add the semicolon anyway, as in:  private static enum EmptyEnum implements EnumKey {
  ;
  @Override
  public String key() {
   return null;
  }
 }

Comment: that's cheeky :)

Answer (score 25):

The enum constants must be [first in the enum definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), above the `private` variable.

> Java requires that the constants be defined first, prior to any fields or methods.

Try:

```
public enum Day {
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY;
    private String mood;
    Day(String mood) {

    }
    Day() {

    }
  }
```

Comment: Cool, got it. But, in no way this is related to `strictfp`, right?

Comment: No.  My guess is that the Eclipse parser messed up.  Your code had an error, but the error had nothing to do with `strictfp`.

Comment: correct, Enum constants should first. then after we can write private variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define instance variable before enum elements/attributes.

```
public enum Day {
   
    MONDAY("sad"), TUESDAY("good"), WEDNESDAY("fresh");
    private String mood;
    Day(String mood) {
    this.mood = mood;
 }
```