# Should I use `strictfp` modifier when converting `float` to `double`?

Tags: java, floating-point, strictfp

If I want to write method converting from float to double.

Is there any case the two would give back different result?

Which version should I use if I don't care about platform consistency?

What if I need it to behave consistently in different platforms?

```
  double f2d(float x) {
    return (double) x;
  }
```

or:

```
  strictfp double f2d(float x) {
    return (double) x;
  }
```

JLS 5.1.2:

> A widening primitive conversion from float to double that is not strictfp may lose information about the overall magnitude of the converted value.

why will this conversion lose info?

Comment: Are you planning on using an AS/400 or Mainframe?

Comment: Most likely you don't need this function. Can you give an example of how it would be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use the "strictfp" keyword in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517915/when-should-i-use-the-strictfp-keyword-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strictfp` will make no difference for `float` to `double` conversion. The reason is in Java Language Specification, 
[4.2.3. Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3). In particular:

> Note that the constraints in Table 4.2.3-A are designed so that every
>   element of the float value set is necessarily also an element of the
>   float-extended-exponent value set, the double value set, and the
>   double-extended-exponent value set.

Since every element of the `float` value set is also an element of the `double` value set a `float` to `double` conversion will be exact regardless of whether it is FP-strict or not.