# Example of Code with and without strictfp Modifier

Tags: java, floating-point, precision, ieee-754, strictfp

I know this question might seem overly familiar to the community, but I swear I've never been able to reproduce the issue related to this question even once throughout my programming journey.

I understand what the `strictfp` modifier does and how it ensures full compliance with the **IEEE754** standard. However, I've never encountered a situation in practice where the set of values with an extended exponent is used, as described in the official specification.

I've tried using options like `-XX:+UseFPUForSpilling` to stimulate the use of the **FPU block** for calculations on my relatively modern processor, but it had no effect.

I even went as far as installing **Windows 98 SE** on a virtual machine and emulating an **Intel Pentium II** processor through **Bochs**, which does not support the **SSE instruction set**, hoping that the use of the **FPU block** in this case would be virtually the only option. However, even such an experiment yielded no results.

The essence of the experiment was to take the maximum possible value of the `double` type and multiply it by 2 to take the intermediate result beyond the permissible range of the `double` type. Then, I divided the obtained value by 4, and the final result was saved back into a `double` variable. In theory, I should have gotten some more meaningful result, but in all situations, I ended up with `Infinity`. In general, I haven't found a single reproducible example on the entire internet (even as of 2024!) that would show different results with and without the use of `strictfp`. Is it really possible that in almost 30 years of the language's history, there isn't a single example on this topic that clearly demonstrates the difference?

P.S. I'm well aware of **Java 17+**. All experiments were conducted on earlier versions, where the difference should, in theory, be observable. I installed **Java SE 1.3** on the virtual machine.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71181138/5133585 Quote: "The one (and only time) I needed this was reconciliation with an IBM ZSeries"

Comment: In what context could this have actually been necessary for a mainframe? The point is that sets with an extended exponent are not at all related to increased precision, as the mantissa always continues to occupy either 24 or 53 bits (including the implicit bit of normalization) depending on the data type (float or double). What was it needed for there? Was work being done with extremely large and/or small numerical values? Was this needed to obtain some kind of meaningful result that would differ from zero or Infinity?

Comment: Many genuinely believe that this is about increased precision, whereas the specification clearly indicates that all this matters only in cases of overflow or loss of significance due to the natural limitations of types. We will never get a final result that falls outside the permissible range of values for the float or double types. However, playing with intermediate results that could lead us to something more meaningful makes sense!

Comment: And even if a programmer used strictfp in the context of working with a mainframe, it doesn't necessarily mean that it was really justified in their case. This issue is so nebulous that many think they understand what they're doing, but in reality, it doesn't always match up. Nevertheless, even if it worked as we assume, why can't we reproduce this on the x86 architecture, even when using old processors like the Intel Pentium or Intel Pentium II?

Comment: The non-strictfp behaviour is only about allowing Java to use certain optimized instructions of the x87 processor that doesn't (fully) comply with IEEE-754 behaviour. It doesn't magically increase the precision of `double` to allow intermediate results of 2x the maximum double value... It just means that certain operations might have (slightly) different result or a different subnormal value than prescribed by IEEE-754.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Yes, I completely agree with what you're writing. However, I would like to be able to reproduce this in practice. Or at least understand in which case this is really possible... For example, I was assured that this can be observed on x86 as well, but I haven't seen a single example of code that would clearly demonstrate this difference. Do you understand me? And as for the "different" result, as far as I understand, it exclusively concerns intermediate results of calculations. The final result will always be cast to the double or float type.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, What does this give us in the end? It means that the result will always represent one of the fixed numerical values that falls within the permissible range of values for the float and double types. All these values are predefined and known, as their number is finite, and the numbers themselves are rational. This means that we are talking about a finite set, which has a cardinality that can be expressed using a natural number. And the specification itself clearly states that the use of an extended exponent may make some sense only in the case of overflow or underflow.

Comment: With different I mean that some values might be one or a few epsilon off from the value that IEEE-754 would require for a calculation.

Comment: And it's entirely possible that you will only observe the difference if the code is optimized by HotSpot.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, 
I initially thought the same, to be honest, but now I see it differently. And how is the result supposed to differ by several epsilons if the extended set does not provide greater precision? The size of the mantissa remains the same; there can be no talk of more accurate values within the same order (exponent). At least, that was the emphasis in the JLS. That is, it makes sense when going beyond the bit grid when working with very large or very small values.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, And this can be interesting when the intermediate result under normal conditions would be equal to zero or infinity, which would devalue all further calculations. Increased precision provides the opportunity to return to the permissible range during calculations, as in the example I described in the body of the question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Certainly, everything depends on the machine code generated by the Java Virtual Machine. It's just not entirely clear how to make the JVM use 80-bit FPU registers, which would allow observing this difference. That's why I thought that more experienced colleagues might have dealt with this and could provide a specific configuration in which all this could be observed.